# Invoke github workflow on serverless deploy

Tags: github, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, github-actions, git-workflow

I have a serverless nodejs project with aws lambda that I am trying to deploy. Before deploying i want to decrypt certain files and then trigger the actual deployment

This is the content of my *main.yml* file inside *.github/workflows* directory

```
name: Test

on: [deployment]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@test
    - name: Decrypting files
      run: <decrypt commands here>
    - name: Actual Serverless Deployment
      run: sls deploy -s staging
```

It is not getting invoked if i do sls deploy. I am intrigued how github will know that its a deployment event if i trigger *sls deploy* command. Please help me in understanding when exactly the above **deployment** event will be triggered. 
What I am trying to achieve is to start a deployment command(ie., **sls deploy -s staging** or the like) and that invokes the above workflow -> (action1)decrypts files -> (action2)triggers actual deployment to lambda.

PS: The exact thing is working fine on git push, but i dont want it to deploy on every push to repo.

Please help me in understanding this. I am very new to github workflows.

Answer (score 0):

The `deployment` event occurs when a deployment is started, completed, etc.
You can use Github Api to create a deployment: `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/deployments` (further details here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/#create-a-deployment)

Alternatively, you can use

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
```

to run your workflow only if something is merged to master.

Comment: So, the only way to trigger deployment event is for me to call the GitHub API call as a hook on my original deploy command (i.e, serverless deploy)?

Comment: I haven't worked with Github deployments up to now. For me it was sufficient to run "my" deployments whenever a merge to master or whenever a "v***" tag was set.
Afaik Github deployment events are often triggered by 3rd party integrations, like now.sh -> so you can listen to those to ex. run your e2e tests afterwards.

Comment: Any idea how i can pick the environment(say, stage or production) in that case? Else everytime i merge to master, it will deploy to all environments right? Without having seperate branches for each environment

Comment: It should be fairy easy to decide what env to deploy based on the tag or branch name. Github Action provide lots of information as [environment variables](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables).